# Camel ApacheMQ -> AHC behaviour (blocking?)

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, asynchttpclient

I just started using Apache Camel and I'm curious about the seemingly counter-intuitive default behaviour of asynchronous http client (AHC). While consuming messages from ActiveMQ, I can't get it to act in a non-blocking fashion.

My route looks like this:

```java
@Component
public class Broadcaster extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("activemq:failed.messages"));

    from("activemq:outbound.messages")
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
    .recipientList(simple("ahc:${in.header[PublishDestination]}"))
    .end();
  }
}
```

I enqueued several messages, half of which I sent to a delayed web server, and the other half to a normal one. I expected to see all the normal messages consumed immediately by the fast server, and the slow messages gradually over time. However, this was the behaviour observed on the fast web server:

```
00:24:02.585, <hello>World</hello>
00:24:03.622, <hello>World</hello>
00:24:04.640, <hello>World</hello>
00:24:05.658, <hello>World</hello>
```

As you can see there is exactly one second between each logged request that corresponds to the artificial 1 second delay on the slow server. Based on the route timings, it looks like the JMS consumer is waiting for AHC to complete before it consumes the next message off the queue:

```
Processor                                 Elapsed (ms)
[activemq://outbound.messages           ] [      1020]
[setExchangePattern[InOnly]             ] [         0]
[ahc:${in.header[PublishDestination]}}  ] [      1018]
```

Am I supposed to explicitly use async producers and write callback handlers in these cases, or is there something else I'm missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, case of a RTFM I guess, although I ActiveMQ page leaves a lot to be desired in terms of properties available for endpoint configuration.  There should probably be a note to say most (all?) JMS config options are also available for ActiveMQ component. In any case, the solution is to define the consumer as follows:

```
from("activemq:outbound.messages?asyncConsumer=true")
```

Comment: See the _options_ section on the ActiveMQ page basically says that in one line of text. > See Options on the JMS component as all these options also apply for this component.

Comment: Thanks, skimming is a bad habbit :)